# Regression on a change between a variable before and after?

Tags: regression, t-test, repeated-measures, spss, paired-data

In my dissertation I am using a paired sample t test to see if there is a statistically significant difference between consumers' intention to purchase from and attitudes towards purchasing from a company before and after viewing a political position that company has taken publicly. However, I also wanted to see if the consumers' existing political beliefs/stances mediated any change in attitude towards purchase. I don't know if this is possible as I wanted to use a regression but I wanted to see if it mediated the change and I am unsure how to do this.

Does anyone know if this is possible and how it can be done? I measure the consumers' existing support or opposition to the issue on a 7 point scale and I also have used 7 point scales for attitude and purchase intention which are measured before and after the respondents view the company's political stance (I am using the theory of planned behaviour but get an overall measure of intention and attitude).

I'm very confused and looking for any help! I have not sent out the survey yet so it could be somewhat changed but my advisor said I would be able to do a regression. I am using SPSS.

Comment: Bravo for asking this early.  You'll want to look into ANOVA + ANCOVA.  A tricky question is whether to use as your outcome a) the posttest rating, while controlling for the pretest rating + mediator, or b) the *difference* ("gain score") between pre and post, again while controlling for mediator.  Or both!  Lots of ink on this:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3466/best-practice-when-analysing-pre-post-treatment-control-designs, https://pareonline.net/getvn.asp?v=14&n=6, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/355228/when-to-use-repeated-measures-versus-anova-on-differences

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17724/how-should-one-control-for-group-and-individual-differences-in-pre-treatment-sco?rq=1